# Docusign document and transaction history after promoting to Live

Tags: docusignapi

I'm wondering what will happen with all the signed documents and transaction history after promoting some integrator key to live account?

Will they be available under new live account? And would it be possible to retreive this documents status/download them using the REST API "service integration" on behalf of live account?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documents used in Demo is only for testing purpose and it has a Red Seal/watermark on each documents which says that this document is for testing/Demonstration purpose. All completed documents in the Demo automatically get purged, as this environment was provided to developers for development/testing. Live (Prod) and Demo are two separate environments and documents sent from one environment cannot be retrieved from another environment. Promoting IntegratorKey to live environment means that it has been whitelisted in DocuSign to use this Integrator Key in the PROD Accounts, it is like a flag to DocuSign to call DS APIs. Once IK is promoted to PROD then you can continue to use that IK both in DEMO and PROD environments.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Data in the DocuSign Demo environment (i.e., developer sandbox) is completely isolated/separate from the DocuSign Production environment. Therefore -- Envelopes, Users, and other data within a DocuSign Demo account will **never** be available within a DocuSign Production account.

Although I believe that you should still be able to use your Integrator Key to issue API requests against the Demo environment, even after the Integrator Key has been approved for use within the Production environment -- migrating Envelopes from the Demo environment to the Production environment isn't feasible for a number of reasons. The DocuSign Demo environment should be used exclusively for development/testing purposes -- you shouldn't be doing "real" work there that you later want/need to appear in your Production DocuSign account.

Comment: Thank you, Kim, for your response. It's much clearer now.